# How to use user defined function for jquery chaining

Tags: jquery

My requirement is like jquery chaining with user defined function

I tried following code.

```
var content = $('<div />', {
  'id': 'pia_editable_'
}).change(function(e) {
  alert('change called');
}).condchain(some values);

function condchain(v) {
  alert('hh');
}
```

It is throwing not defined function error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that jQuery recognises your function, it needs to be added to `$.fn.`

```
$.fn.condchan = function() { };
```

this then gives you access to `this` which would be the current jquery context, eg:

```js
$.fn.myFunc = function(txt) { var that = this; setTimeout(function() { that.text(txt) }, 500); };
$("#div").myFunc("changed");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>text</div>
```

In order to add *chaining* you simply need to return `this`.  You can also use `$(this).each...` if you want to do anything more than a bulk operation, eg:

```js
$.fn.myFunc = function(txt) { 
  // this = jquery context
  $(this).each(function(i, e) {
    // this now = loop iteration
    var that = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function() { that.text(txt) }, 500 * (i + 1)); 
  });
  return this;
};

$(".div").myFunc("changed").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div'>text</div>
<div class='div'>text</div>
```

There's more you can do to create a fully fledged reusable plugin and this page should be your starting point: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: i tried, but still getting this error. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).change(...).condchain is not a function
    at PostItAll.create (jquery.postitall.js:2417)
    at PostItAll.init (jquery.postitall.js:967)
    at jquery.postitall.js:656

Comment: Can you create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net to demonstrate it not working?

Comment: You need to make sure `$.fn.condchain` code is *before* `$(..).condchain()`, example: https://jsfiddle.net/nojsfk5c/  (it's after in your original code)

Comment: Have a read of [mcve].  I'm not asking for your library, I'm asking for a snippet that demonstrates it *not* working as I've provided a snippet showing that it *does work* - so there must be something different in your code that you've not told us

Answer (score 2):

Put the function on `$.fn` instead:

```
$.fn.condchain = function condchain(v) {
  alert('hh');
}
var content = $('', { 'id': 'pia_editable_' })
  .change(function(e) {
    alert('change called');
  })
  .condchain(some values);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is extend JQuery functions with your custom functions like in the above comment you can use 
`$.fn.<some_function_name> =  function(params){};`
 to extend native jQ functions 
Please refer [What does $.fn mean in jQuery?](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/what-does-fn-mean-in-jquery.html) for more details.

Thanks, 
Happy Coding <3 !